# How to sovle memory limit and spend less time when merge two big tables with python？

Tags: python, merge

I got two tables/dataframe to merge, which have the same key column. However, the shape of the table is more than(100M,5), I tried merge\map, or just load data one by one, the result is not ideal. What should I do?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If can achieve that the tables are sorted by the key, then you can read them line-by-line and write the merge also line-by-line, without the need to keep everything in memory.